# Alone, together, and with friends

Tags: riddle

Alone I stand between the 23rd and the 25th,
together with a friend I am 20,
and if another friend joins in, we will be dirty.

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's

> The letter X

Because

> X is the 24th letter of the alphabet
>  XX means 20 in Roman numerals

The only thing I'm not 100% sure of is the "dirty" part

> I guess XXX can bring to mind... activities which may not be exactly clean?

Comment: If you are older than 18, then you may want to do an internet search for the "dirty" part.

Comment: Haha yeah that's what I was trying to reference.. :P